# OpenCV - get coordinates of top of object in contour

Tags: opencv

Given a contour such as the one seen below, is there a way to get the X,Y coordinates of the top point in the contour?  I'm using Python, but other language examples are fine.

[image]

Comment: take a look at [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/64433/converting-python-to-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Since every pixel needs to be checked, I'm afraid you will have to iterate linewise over the image and see which is the first white pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the image until you encounter a pixel that isn't black.

I will write an example in C++.

```
cv::Mat image;  // your binary image with type CV_8UC1 (8-bit 1-channel image)
int topRow(-1), topCol(-1);
for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
    uchar* ptr = image.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        if(ptr[j] != 0) {
             topRow = i;
             topCol = j;
             std::cout << "Top point: " << i << ", " << j << std::endl;
             break;
        }
    }
    if(topRow != -1)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Does your example iterate though all the pixels or just the contour's pixels?  It looks like the whole image, but then what if there are multiple contours in the image?